# Gesture on UIBezierPath and not to the entire UIView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiview, uibezierpath

I drew an UIBezierPath in an UIView in Swift. My UIBezierPath has a different shape than the UIView. Therefore I want only to detect gestures (tap, pan, rotate) in UIBezierPath and not in the entire UIView.

For example, if I have a triangle, I can pan it around even if I click outside the triangle, but inside the UIView.

Has someone a solution to this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Your English sentences are not comprehensible.

Comment: See the documentation for `UIBezierPath` - in particular, the section on **Hit Detection** and `func contains(CGPoint)`: [link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibezierpath)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you have a code example? The problem is that my path is drawn in the UIView and the gesture is in the UIViewController?